# Get headers from response with Spring Boot 2 WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I would like to receive the headers (especially the content-type) from the webclient response.
I found this code with flatmap-mono-getHeaders, but it doesn't work.

`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'image/tiff' not supported for bodyType=org.company.MyResponse`

How can I fix it? Or maybe can someone recommend a simpler solution.

```
Mono<Object> mono = webClient.get()
                                .uri(path)
                                .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                .retrieve()
                                .toEntity(MyResponse.class)
                                .flatMap(entity -> Mono.justOrEmpty(entity.getHeaders().getFirst("content-type")));
Object rs = mono.block();
public class MyResponse {
 Object body;
 Integer status;
 String contentType;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to receive the headers (especially the content-type) from the webclient response

Generally speaking you can access response headers like this:

```java
ResponseEntity<MyResponse> response = webClient.get()
        .uri(path)
        .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(MyResponse.class)
        .block();
HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
MediaType contentType = headers.getContentType();
```

**But** from the error you pasted it appears that you are accessing an image (`image/tiff`) that obviously cannot be converted to your `MyResponse` class.

Comment: yes, the response is an image. I don't want to convert the response to a class, if it's not necessary. That was the only useful example what I found that's why I tried it. 
I just want the header content-type.
So there are no way to get the headers if the response is an image? 
If I use the .get().uri().retrieve() and some onStatus() , I get ResponseSpec which doesn't have .getHeaders().

Comment: If you are only interested in the response headers you could perform a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET`. Also you can use `.toBodilessEntity()` instead of `.toEntity(MyResponse.class)`.

Comment: Thank you! It almost works. I tried with .toEntity( String.class ) , and I received the headers and the image also. But when I write into a file, the string, the characters are not the same as in the real tif image and I cannot open the file.  I tried  with  .toEntity( MultipartFile ) also, but it again 'not supported'. Maybe I can call it other than Multipart? Or the error is in the character encoding?

Comment: It seems, the standard characters are good ( a, b, c... ) but the "original tiff" image has 'm=p`¶ŕ¸żĂh '  and  'w˙ü/˙Č'  charachters which I don't have in the response. I just have rectangles....  I changed the UTF_8 to UTF_16BE, and ISO_8859_1 , but the result is the same.

Comment: Try `.toEntity(byte[].class)`