# How to get specific HTTP header values from an HTTP response in Java?

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, httpresponse

For example, you can extract the status code from a CloseableHTTPResponse using `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`.

Is there a similar way to get a specific header value (ie. Location, Date, etc.) from the response (in String format)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69283119/get-headers-from-response-with-spring-boot-2-webclient this may be  helpful to you

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `getFirstHeader("key")`.

Apache HttpClient example:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://api.com");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

//get header by 'key'
String headerName= response.getFirstHeader("headerName").getValue();
```

If you want to get all the headers, you can use `getAllHeaders()`.

```
//get all headers       
    Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (Header header : headers) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() 
              + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
    }
```